# "task.isSuccesful" is not recognize by Android Studio ("Cannot resolve symbol 'task' ")

Tags: java, android, firebase

Im really not sure what the problem could be, Im following a tutorial of a [Whatsapp clone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=988UZFB0heA&list=PL1v4ZzsmkiOLWNANnwt1ZHp8tNqlmejJm&index=2&t=270s) and I have followed every step, but still Android Studio doesnt recognized, I really dont know whats wrong. Im just taking my first steps into programming.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mPhoneNumber, mCode;
    private Button mSend;

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;

    String mVerificationId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        userIsLoggedIn();

        mPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id. phoneNumber);
        mCode = findViewById(R.id.code);

        mSend = findViewById(R.id.send);

        mSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mVerificationId != null)
                    verifyPhoneNumberWithCode();
                else
                    startPhoneNumberVerification();
            }
        });

        mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(String verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                super.onCodeSent(verificationId, forceResendingToken);

                mVerificationId = verificationId;
                mSend.setText("Verify Code");

            }
        };
    }

    private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(){
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, mCode.getText().toString());
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            }if(task.isSuccesful()){    // **here is the PROBLEM**
                    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                    if (user != null){
                        final DatabaseReference mUserDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(user.getUid());
                        mUserDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if (!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                    Map<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                                    userMap.put("phone", user.getPhoneNumber());
                                    userMap.put("name", user.getPhoneNumber());
                                    mUserDB.updateChildren(userMap);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                        });
                    }
                }
                    //userIsLoggedIn();

        });
    }

    private void userIsLoggedIn() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null){
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPageActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }

    private void startPhoneNumberVerification() {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                mPhoneNumber.getText().toString(),
                60,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                this,
                mCallbacks);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probobly you need to put ur code inside

```
 @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
**-----here is your code------**
            }if(task.isSuccesful()){
```

hope it helps)

Comment: Thanks for your help! turns out it was just an extra curly bracket and I was missing a letter

Comment: Actually that worked too!! The changes I said I made created more erros across the code, but then I just did what you said and everything was fixed! Thank you so much!! You're awesome

Answer (score 0):

There is a curly bracket too much:

```
}if(task.isSuccesful()){
```

should be

```
if(task.isSuccesful()) {
```

Comment: It Worked! also changed "isSuccesful" to "isSuccessful" LoL, thanks man!!